# Track time to click in Google analytics 4/ Google tag manager?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I've been trying to track the time spent on a page in seconds until CTA click occurs.
I would preferably like to send this data together with a custom click event that i've made. Meaning i can see number of clicks on this button and time spent on page before clicking the CTA

Is it possible to do this by just adding a On-screen duration parameter to the tag?
Or what would be the most simple way?

Answer (score 0):

You could push a timestamp to the DataLayer on page load.
This way, you can calculate the duration by subtracting the page load time stamp from the cta click time stamp.

Tage that fires on Page Load (the earlier the more accurate):

```
<script>
(function(){
  var tStamp = Date.now();
  dataLayer.push({
    'event':'pageLoadTime',
    'pageLoadTime': tStamp
  });
})();
</script>
```

Now you have the page loads timestamp in your DataLayer.
In addtition to that, you create a custom JS var, that subtracts the current timestamp from page load time:

```
function pageDuration() {
  var loadTime = {{}}, //your DataLayer var that captures the timestamp from the above tag
      clickTime = Date.now();
  return clickTime - loadTime;
}
```

Using some more JavaScript, you can transform the return value from milliseconds to seconds, minutes and so on...

Comment: Ok thank you very much! Will try this. I have one question regarding the js snippet and the variable loadTime, should i copy just like u did or replace with "tStamp" etc? 
So var loadTime = tStamp?

Comment: You can use it the way I've shared it in my post. The only thing, that you need to add, is the dataLayer variable you created for pageLoadTime in the second line of the second snippet:

var loadTime = {{}}, //your DataLayer var that captures the timestamp from the above tag

Comment: Ok got it, then to apply this to a click event, do I add the JS var as an event parameter?

Comment: Yes, that's how it is done :)